# How to require functional dependencies in kind signature?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Consider the following code:

```
type CFunctor f = forall x y. (x -> y -> Constraint) -> f x -> f y -> Constraint

type MapList :: CFunctor []
class MapList c xs ys
instance MapList c '[] '[]
instance (c x y, MapList c xs ys) => MapList c (x ': xs) (y ': ys)
```

This works fine, but it's desirable in some situations to "make things compute" by introducing a functional dependency of the form:

```
class MapList c xs ys | c xs -> ys
```

With the functional dependency we have the following code:

```
type CFunctor f = forall x y. (x -> y -> Constraint) -> f x -> f y -> Constraint

type MapList :: CFunctor []
class MapList c xs ys | c xs -> ys
instance MapList c '[] '[]
instance (c x y, MapList c xs ys) => MapList c (x ': xs) (y ': ys)
```

This does not compile however, and produces the following error on the last instance:

```
[typecheck] [E] • Illegal instance declaration for ‘MapList c (x : xs) (y : ys)’
    The liberal coverage condition fails in class ‘MapList’
      for functional dependency: ‘c xs -> ys’
    Reason: lhs types ‘c’, ‘x : xs’
      do not jointly determine rhs type ‘y : ys’
    Un-determined variable: y
• In the instance declaration for ‘MapList c (x : xs) (y : ys)’
```

This makes sense: `c + xs` determines `ys` due to the recursive use of `MapList c xs ys` (which has a functional dependency). But `c + x ': xs` determines `c + y ': ys` only if `x` determines `y`, which is a property we must require of the class being passed in for `c`.

But how can we adjust the `CFunctor` kind to demand this? As far as I'm aware there is no vocabulary in kind signatures to discuss functional dependencies. Is there still a way I can make this work?

Comment: You might be able to exploit the 'horrific' dodginess here: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/18759, see also #18851. Try `instance (c x y => c x y, MapList c xs ys) => MapList c (x ': xs) (y ': ys)`. That `c x y => c x y` is a quantified aka implication constraint. They're not supposed to be self-covering like that; but if it works please add a comment to that ticket. We need real-life examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One workaround is to create a wrapper class that simply demands whatever your original constraint was, plus a functional dependency. The only way to satisfy the functional dependency in the wrapper is to have a functional dependency in the original class.

To wit:

```
type FDep :: (a -> b -> Constraint) -> a -> b -> Constraint
class c x y => FDep c x y | c x -> y
```

Now we can write:

```
type MapList :: CFunctor []
class MapList c xs ys | c xs -> ys
instance MapList (FDep c) '[] '[]
instance (FDep c x y, MapList (FDep c) xs ys) => MapList (FDep c) (x ': xs) (y ': ys)
```

And have it type check.

When passing in some arrow, e.g.:

```
class Fst ab a | ab -> a
instance Fst '(a, b) a
```

We simply instantiate `FDep` for it as well, to witness the fact that it has the relevant functional dependency:

```
instance Fst ab a => FDep Fst ab a
```

Somewhat curiously, our functor mappings are closed with respect to `FDep`-ness, as illustrated below:

```
type MapList :: CFunctor []
class MapList c xs ys | c xs -> ys
instance MapList c xs ys => FDep (MapList c) xs ys

instance MapList (FDep c) '[] '[]
instance (FDep c x y, MapList (FDep c) xs ys) => MapList (FDep c) (x ': xs) (y ': ys)
```

This is nice, because it allows functors to compose arbitrarily. It suggests we are doing some kind of weird `Constraint` enriched category theory whose objects are kinds, and whose morphisms are functionally dependent classes.

Here is a worked example of using our type level computer:

```
(^$) :: FDep c x y => Proxy c -> Proxy x -> Proxy y
(^$) _ _ = Proxy

class Fst ab a | ab -> a
instance Fst ab a => FDep Fst ab a

instance Fst '(a, b) a

test :: _
test = Proxy @(MapList (FDep Fst)) ^$ Proxy @'[ '(0, 1)]
```

The type hole error that results is:

```
[typecheck] [E] • Found type wildcard ‘_’ standing for ‘Proxy '[0]’
  To use the inferred type, enable PartialTypeSignatures
• In the type signature: test :: _
```